# xtable - how do I set both the column width and column text justification

Tags: r, latex, knitr, xtable

I'm trying to create a Latex table with `xtable`. Some of my column names are rather long, so I decided to fix the width of the the respective columns. However, once I fix the width of the columns I lose the column justification.

**Simplified example:**

```
counts <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
temp <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts)
temp2.table <- xtable(temp)
align(temp2.table) <- "rp{1in}cc" 
colnames(temp2.table)[1] <- "This column title label is too long"
```

I would like the numbers which appear in the first column to be right justified.

Comment: You'll find an answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/raggedleft-paragraph-in-a-table